# INSERT with mysqli

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I have a register page which inserts the registration data into a database.
It goes along the lines of this:

```
if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['conf_pass']){
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        $hash = md5(rand(0,1000));

        $accres = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO accounts (street1, suburb, city, postcode, username) VALUES($address, $suburb, $city, $postcode, $username)");
        $account_id = mysqli_insert_id($accres);
        $peopleres = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO people (lastname, firstname, accounts_id, birthdate, phonenumber, username, password, email, hash) VALUES($lastname, $firstname, $account_id, $birthdate, $phonenumber, $username, $password, $email, $hash)");

        $peoplerows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($peopleres);
        $person_id=$peoplerows[0];

        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO PeopleToRole (role_id) VALUES(1)");
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $p->addContent("User Registered");
}
```

I originally programmed all of this using postgres (while hosted locally on an apache server) but had to change to mysqli because the host website was already working with mysqli.

So, this code returns the User Registered on the page, therefore the if statement is working. But for some reason the insert statement won't insert anything into the database.

Do i have some sort of formatting error? or something small that i've missed?
Any and all help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use placeholders. Your data is vulnerable to sql injection! Check for errors! It will tell you exactly what is wrong (which is that your variables aren't quoted.)

Comment: "Do i have some sort of formatting error? or something small that i've missed?" are offtopic questions here, mind you.

Comment: If the code worked with Postgres and not mySql, it's probably some sort of database setup issue.  Check the accounts, privileges, error logs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the quotes in the query, for example, you should change:

```
"INSERT INTO accounts (street1, suburb, city, postcode, username) VALUES($address, $suburb, $city, $postcode, $username)"
```

to:

```
"INSERT INTO accounts (street1, suburb, city, postcode, username) VALUES('$address', '$suburb', '$city', '$postcode', '$username')"
```

That said, working like this makes your code vulnerable to sql injection (as cfreak mentioned in the comments above).

Here's a small example from *[the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)* that shows how you can use `bind_param()` to make the code more secure:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, why even mention a revision to the first incorrect way of querying? The entire point of mysqli is to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @user113215 when I'm providing an answer I like to cover everything... ;)

Comment: I gave this a `+1` because it's the only one to mention the quoting issue, which is *most likely* what the problem is.

Comment: @user113215 Actually, the 'whole point' of `mysqli` is to provide support for new database features not supported in `mysql_*()`. Prepared statements is just one, but the blanket approach of 'prepare everything' has led to some of the worst implementations of database interfaces I have ever seen. There is no substitute for understanding what you're doing and using the tools appropriately.

Comment: @MikeW For the purposes of this question, there's no doubt the OP should be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem: you're not bothering to check your queries for errors, so when something goes wrong you don't know what's happened.

Check the return value of `mysqli_query()` for `FALSE`, and if you find it, check `mysqli_error($connection)` for an error message.

For example:

```
$accres = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO accounts (street1, suburb, city, postcode, username) VALUES($address, $suburb, $city, $postcode, $username)");
if ($accres === false) {die(mysqli_error($connection));}
```

Do something similar for your other queries. When you have an error message, fix it, or come back and ask again.